# Configuring programs and services from unstable channel in NixOS

Tags: nixos

I know that I can install a package from the unstable channel like this:

```
{ config, pkgs, ... }:
let
  unstable-pkgs = import <unstable> {};
in
{
  environment.systemPackages = [ unstable-pkgs.chromium ]
}
```

This shows that `import <unstable> {};` stands in for `pkgs` in my configuration, but what if I want to do the same thing for `programs` or `services`?

Comment: It seems this is covered here: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/41212

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want to use the stable channel for most of your system, but get some specific programs or services from the unstable channel. You can do this by importing the specific modules you need from unstable.

However, if that module also exists in the **stable** channel, then the two modules will conflict. You can use `disabledModules` to suppress the existing module from the stable channel.

For example, this is how I load just the `plymouth` module from the unstable channel:

```
{ nixpkgs-unstable, ... }:
{
  imports = [
    "${nixpkgs-unstable}/nixos/modules/system/boot/plymouth.nix"
  ];
  disabledModules = [
    "system/boot/plymouth.nix"
  ];
}
```

This is on a system using Flakes, where `nixpkgs-unstable` is defined as a Flake input *and* that input is passed as part of `specialArgs` when invoking `nixosSystem` to build the system configuration. However, `imports` and `disabledModules` are not Flakes-specific, so you should be able to do the same thing on a non-Flakes system as long as you can provide a path to the module from the unstable channel.